# Why can I not run my .exe converted wxPython file? AttributeError

Tags: python, wxpython, executable, attributeerror

This is the output I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "ConvertImagesWithInterface.py", line 1, in (module)
    File "wx\__init__.pyc", line 45, in (module)
    File "wx\_core.pyc", line 5, in (module)
    File "new.pyc", line 3, in (module)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Frame'
```

I have tried copying `__init__` files and `new.pyc` files into different directories relevant to the (module) location, tried renaming things inside of the module, and looked at about 20 different problems other people have, but I cannot find an answer how to fix this. Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

```
import wx as wxPython
import os

try:
# Python2
import Tkinter as tk
import tkFileDialog as tkfd

except ImportError:
# Python3
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.filedialog as tkfd

newFileName = "" 
newFolderName = "new folder/"
newDirectory = "" 
path = ""
jpgType = ".jpg"
pngType = ".png"
filesConverted = ""
numberOfFiles = 0
```

class greg(wxPython.Frame):

```
def __init__(self, parent, id):
    wxPython.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, 'Convert Images', size = (160, 110))
    panel = wxPython.Panel(self)

    button = wxPython.Button(panel, label = "exit", pos = (10, 10), size = (60, 60))
    self.Bind(wxPython.EVT_BUTTON, self.closebutton, button)
    self.Bind(wxPython.EVT_CLOSE, self.closewindow)

    button = wxPython.Button(panel, label = "convert", pos = (80, 10), size = (60, 60))
    self.Bind(wxPython.EVT_BUTTON, self.file_open, button)



def closebutton(self, event):
    self.Close(True)

def closewindow(self, event):
    self.Destroy()

def file_open(self, event):
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.withdraw() 
    path = tkfd.askdirectory(parent=root,initialdir="/",title='Please select a directory') + "/"

    directoryFiles = os.listdir(path)
    newDirectory = path + newFolderName
    convert(newDirectory, directoryFiles, path);

    temp = wxPython.MessageDialog( self, filesConverted, "About Sample Editor", wxPython.OK | wxPython.CENTRE)
    temp.ShowModal()
    quit()


def convert(newDir, dirFiles, filePath):
if not os.path.exists(newDir):
    os.makedirs(newDir)
for x in range(0, len(dirFiles)):
    fileName = dirFiles[x]
    fileType = fileName[(len(fileName)-10):-6]
    if jpgType == fileType or pngType == fileType:
        fileNametoReadFrom = filePath + fileName
        file = open(fileNametoReadFrom, 'rb')
        text = file.read()
        file.close()
        newFileName = filePath + newFolderName + "new " + fileName[:-6]
        file = open(newFileName, 'wb')
        file.write(text[4:-13])
        file.close()
        global filesConverted
        filesConverted = filesConverted + str(numberOfFiles) + ": Converted: " + fileNametoReadFrom + "\n"
        global numberOfFiles
        numberOfFiles = numberOfFiles + 1
filesConverted = filesConverted + "\n" + str(numberOfFiles) + " files have been placed in " + filePath + newFolderName


if __name__ == '__main__':
app = wxPython.PySimpleApp()
frame = greg(parent = None, id = -1)
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Your misusing .Frame somewhere.  Can you show the source of new.py?

Comment: @chown, new.pyc is part of the python lib.

Comment: Then can you show `ConvertImagesWithInterface.py` or whatever your .py file is?

Comment: @user585025 is the python program running (Only the exe fails)?

Comment: Few things. What are you using to create the .exe file? Do you have multiple versions of python on your machine? If so, are you sure you're specifying using the one that has wx installed?

Comment: I'm with Manny D: what are you using to create the .exe file? If you are using py2exe, it is bad for skipping libraries it has trouble finding (though wxPython has never been an issue for me). Usually the build output lists any dependancies it didn't find.

Comment: I am using py2exe. The program works just fine when I run it though the Python Shell, it finds all the libraries it needs. 

Manny D, I am not sure that I am using the right Python, I have Python 27 and 26 installed, I am thinking about trying another .exe program, like PyInstaller or something else I will find.

Comment: I used pyinstaller and it worked just fine, don't know why py2exe didn't work, but also it wasn't working in the python shell because I had new.py in the folder, and it was looking for that. I deleted it and it works perfect now. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I can't mark this as answered for some reason but it is answered, or at least fixed.